# Multiple level of inheritance and calling base constructors in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have the following classes that form a multilevel inheritance model.

```
class CavPkoTest : virtual public CavTest
{
public:
    CavPkoTest() : CavTest{CAV_TEST_ID_PKO}, NpBaseTest{CAV_TEST_ID_PKO, MODULE_CAV_TEST} {}
}
class CavTest : virtual public NpBaseTest
{
public:
    CavTest(uint16_t p_testId) : NpBaseTest{p_testId, MODULE_CAV_TEST} {}
}

class NpBaseTest
{
    uint16_t m_testId;
    uint16_t m_moduleType;
public:
    NpBaseTest(uint16_t p_testId, uint16_t p_moduleType) : m_testId{p_testId}, m_moduleType{p_moduleType} {}
}
```

My question is that when `CavPkoTest()` (leaf node) constructor is called, it delegates a call its parent class constructor `CavTest()`. `CavTest()` constructor is declared to explicitly calls its parent `NpBaseTest()` constructor. So why I am required to explicitly call `NpBaseTest()` constructor from `CavPkoTest()` when a call to `CavTest()` constructor should do it for me ?

If I declare `CavPkoTest()` constructor as :

```
class CavPkoTest : virtual public CavTest
{
public:
    CavPkoTest() : CavTest{CAV_TEST_ID_PKO} {}
}
```

FYI : Both `CavTest` and `NpBaseTest` classes are Abstract Base Classes since they have 1+ pure virtual member functions (which are implemented by `CavPkoTest` class)

Comment: All virtual bases are considered immediate bases. You have to call their constructors from any descendants at any level, not just from immediate children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With virtual inheritance, you can have multiple base classes deriving from the same virtual base class.

That virtual base class sub-object must be initialized only once. Hence the language rule, that the derived class must initialize it explicitly.

If the base classes were to initialize the *same* virtual base class sub-object, they would end up initializing it multiple times.

Comment: So what about `CavTest(uint16_t p_testId) : NpBaseTest{p_testId, MODULE_CAV_TEST} {}` ? It seems like a wasted declaration where I pass in `MODULE_CAV_TEST` when I have to do this again in the child class. I mean can I get away with using the implicit constructor for `CavTest` ?

Comment: @nitimalh `CavTest` does not have knowledge whether `NpBaseTest` has already been initialized because there can be multiple `CavTest` base class sub-objects and only one `NpBaseTest` shared between them.

Comment: Ah ok .. I understand and I kind of figured it out. I do not need to pass MODULE_CAV_TEST in the CavTest constructor. I could just declare it as `CavTest(uint16_t p_testId) : NpBaseTest{p_testId, 0} {}`

Comment: BTW how does this change if I were not to use virtual inheritance ?

Comment: @nitimalh If you drop virtual inheritance then the most derived class does not need to initialize the virtual base class that is not its direct base class.

Comment: Perfect I actually should have used non virtual inheritance to begin with. That makes a lot of sense now. Thanks for all your help !